# compare raw bytes from file and not interpreted str bytes

Tags: python

So I have this code which opens a binary file and compares the first "bytes" with 0xE42F:

```
file = open("hello.bin", "rb")
fileStream = file.read()

if(fileStream[0:2] == '\xE4\x2F'):
   print("yes")
else:
   print("no")
```

However the above check returns false since for python, the selected bytes are interpreted as a string hex => `\xE4/` where `0x2F` is interpreted as a string (`/`) and hence makes the check return false.

When I try to use `hex(fileStream[0:2])` it returns `invalid literal for int`

Any idea on how I could make it that python interprets the bytes as a hex int and not a string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `print(fileStream[0])` show?

Comment: you can just convert it as hex(filestream[0])==0x4D

Comment: You can check that `bytes([0x4D])[0] == 0x4D`, so it does work the way you expect it to work. The reason it prints `"no"` is probably because the first byte isn't `0x4D`.

Comment: @AdityaChavan Do you mean to use `ord` instead of `hex`? `hex` doesn't do what it appears you think it does.

Comment: Please see edit @a_guest

Comment: `0xE42F` is an integer literal expressed in hexadecimal. `fileStream[0:2]` is an instance of class `bytes` — that is what you don't understand.

Comment: @martineau yes, however what fileStream[0:2] returns is a strange hex string and I want to convert the whole to a only hex string

Comment: Please frame your sentences correctly:" where 0x2F is interpreted as / " is not meaningful

Comment: Python (confusingly) will display the _representation_ of `'\xE4\x2F'` as `'ä/'`, and `bytes([0xE4, 0x2F])` as `b'\xe4/'`. In other words, if will display values that happen to be the ordinal value of characters as the character, not the hex value.

Comment: @martineau oh right, is there a way to display the hex values?

Comment: Please see my response below where the first two bytes are read and printed. If it serves your purpose then why convert to hex. It is very important that you state your end goal as well.

Comment: @AajKaal I specified clearly what my end goal was in my updated post, my question was not to know what were the first two bytes of an executable(taken as an example) but how I could interpret arbitrary bytes differently for my comparison, in this case the bytes were not entirely printed since 0x2F was printed as `/`.

Comment: Alex: Yes. One way is to derive your own subclass and define its `__repr__()` method so that it does what you want. Another would be to just write your own utility function that did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a slice on a `bytes` object gives you another `bytes` object, so you need to compare with a bytes object (not with a `str` object).

```py
>>> bytes([0x4D, 0x5A])
b'MZ'
>>> bytes([0x4D, 0x5A]) == b'MZ'
True
```

Comment: I did not know the existance of bytes objects on python, that made it clearer. Thank you

Comment: @Alex Yes, it's the `b` prefix that makes the difference between a `str` and `bytes` object.

Comment: oh ok that makes perfect sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use
fileStream = bytes(file.read())
That worked with .exe

After your Edit:

```
fileStream = bytes(file.read())
if fileStream[0] == 0xE4 and fileStream[1] == 0x2F:
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to reinterpret first two bytes of a file as a `short unsigned int`, to get the value 0xe42f.

To do that in Python, you need to use [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

Now, I am going to assume the bytes in your file are in big endian order i.e. first byte is 0xe4 second byte is 0x2f.

If they are reversed, just switch the first character of the first parameter to `unpack` in the code from '>' to '<'.

```
import struct

file = open("hello.bin", "rb")
fileStream = file.read()

if(struct.unpack(">H", fileStream[0:2])[0] == 0xE42F):
   print("yes")
else:
   print("no")
```

Note, that `struct.unpack` always returns a tuple, even for one element, so you have to index in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever python shows is correct. First two bytes of an EXE file are always 4D 5A, which are the ASCII  codes of two letters MZ.

Code:

```
file = open(r"python.exe", "rb")
fileStream = file.read()

print(fileStream[0:2])
file.close()
```

Output:

```
b'MZ'
```

Comment: This is not what my question is about, please re-read my post.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. It 100% serves your purpose mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

if format(fileStream[0:2],'x') == '4d':

Comment: this returns `unsupported format string passed to bytes.__format__`

Comment: I forgot - I use struct.unpack() first, but I see someone else already posted that.